# Vue removes all class prototype methods from object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Am I missing something here? I have a `Class` which I use to instantiate and create objects. These objects have prototype methods on them.

```
let item = {
  name: 'Television',
  brand: 'Sony'
}

class Product {
  constructor (item) {
    Object.assign(this, item)
  }

  analyzeBrand () {
    // do something here
  }
}

let product1 = new Product(item);
```

And then in my `store`, I add this product to an array

```
commit('addProduct', product1)

mutations: {
  addProduct (item) {
    state.products.unshift(item);
  }
}
```

But then when I inspect the instance of my product later in a Vue component, the prototype method `analyzeBrand` has been removed. What gives?

Comment: Nuts, just edited.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You can't reassign `this` like that.

Comment: You can only store plain objects as data. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data. "The object must be plain: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored"

Comment: Ok, is there an another way of doing this? I suppose in that case, there really isn't any point using Classes with prototype methods on them if Vue is going to just strip them off...

Comment: @RandyCasburn if it's silly, can you propose an alternative?

Comment: @Modermo - apologize: my humor was in bad taste. It is a bit ambiguous. There is nothing technically wrong with what you've done.

Comment: It's `vuex` state. I still can use domain class in `vuex` state as normal.
Can you check `console.log(typeof item)` and call `item.analyzeBrand ()` to check if it's ok in `addProduct` mutation? Just add a simple console log in `analyzeBrand ()` method to check.